# Query to convert from datetime to date mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, date

I am trying to get the date portion of a datetime field. I know I can get it with date_format, but that returns a string or "varchar" field. How can I convert the result to date and not as varchar?

This is my query  returning the varchar:

```
(Select Date_Format(orders.date_purchased,'%m/%d/%Y')) As Date
```

I tried several combinations from this question, but could not make it to work:

[mysql query - format date on output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596457/mysql-query-format-date-on-output)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try to cast it as a DATE

```
SELECT CAST(orders.date_purchased AS DATE) AS DATE_PURCHASED
```

Answer (score 68):

Use the [DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT DATE(orders.date_purchased) AS date
```

Comment: it's giving me that "DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Answer (score 9):

Either Cybernate or OMG Ponies solution will work. The fundamental problem is that the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function returns a string, not a date. When you wrote

```
(Select Date_Format(orders.date_purchased,'%m/%d/%Y')) As Date
```

I think you were essentially asking MySQL to try to format the values in `date_purchased` according to that format string, and instead of calling that column `date_purchased`, call it  "Date". But that column would no longer contain a date, it would contain a string. (Because `Date_Format()` returns a string, not a date.)

I don't think that's what you wanted to do, but that's what you were doing.

Don't confuse how a value looks with what the value is.

Comment: Thanks man, i use this for only year and month

Answer (score 7):

I see the many types of uses, but I find this layout more useful as a reference tool:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2004-01-20' ,'%Y-%m-01');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

syntax of date_format:

```
SELECT date_format(date_born, '%m/%d/%Y' ) as my_date FROM date_tbl

    '%W %D %M %Y %T'    -> Wednesday 5th May 2004 23:56:25
    '%a %b %e %Y %H:%i' -> Wed May 5 2004 23:56
    '%m/%d/%Y %T'       -> 05/05/2004 23:56:25
    '%d/%m/%Y'          -> 05/05/2004
    '%m-%d-%y'          -> 04-08-13
```