# Truncated incorrect date value

Tags: mysql, sql, date

In my situation, I need to deal with invalid date values like: '04070$'. I need to insert something even if I receive erroneous inputs like: '04070$'.

When I do:

```
select str_to_date('04070$','%m%d%Y') from dual;
```

The result is:

```
2000-04-07
```

But for insert statement, I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` ( `Date_Posted`) VALUES (str_to_date('04070$','%m%d%Y'))

#1292 - Truncated incorrect date value: '04070$'
```

I do not understand why select statement runs fine and insert statement gives error. Is there a way to make insert statement insert NULL or date (even if it is incorrect) when presented with such incorrect values?

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740655/131391 helpful when I came across this warning/error..

Comment: INSERT INTO `table1` ( `Date_Posted`) VALUES (str_to_date(LEFT('04070$,6)','%m%d%Y'))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens because MySQL is running on [Strict Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

On a `SELECT` statement, `STR_TO_DATE()` will return a year, but since it wasn't matched 100%, it'll also issue a warning:

```
mysql> SELECT str_to_date('040710$','%m%d%y');
+---------------------------------+
| str_to_date('040710$','%m%d%y') |
+---------------------------------+
| 2010-04-07                      |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the warning is just a little mention on the select result, but it's still exists:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect date value: '040710$' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On Strict Mode, any warning becomes an error when trying to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`. that's why you can see a date on select but can't save it on the database.

Comment: So how to get rid of this warning then? Surely turning off strict mode is not an option. Should we just limit substr the date by 6 digit?

Comment: There's a few options... You can parse the date before sending it, you can use an `insert ignore` statement, or even create a function, if the bulk of your logic is inside the database. It all depends on your application and what fits best :)

Answer (score 6):

Change the year format to uppercase like.

```
str_to_date('01-01-2000','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: The possible __format-specifier__ in relation with MySQL's function [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is described in a [symbols table at `DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is valid . But keep in mind that this is a warning not error.

Row is also inserted in this case. I cross checked it with an example and it works fine.

As MySQL always truncate the column value after matching with the appropriate datatype and truncate the unmatched data or out of range values from the complete string.

Example : If you want to insert 'ABCDEFGHIHJHJ' in char(3), it truncates the string and insert ABC in the row.

Comment: In my case this is an error `Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect datetime value`. It prevent insert while select works fine

Answer (score -2):

The Select Statement as well as the Insert statement will give out error, since the $ wont be considered as a number. It has to be

```
INSERT INTO `table1` ( `Date_Posted`) VALUES (str_to_date('040709','%m%d%Y')).
```

for inserting into table 1 with the entry 2009-04-07

Comment: Yes it does give a MySQL 1292 Error : Truncated incorrect date value: '04070$'

Comment: It might be giving that in your system. It does not give it in mine. Must be some configuration related issue.