# how do I convert date type to hh:mm in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I got in my table two types:

```
hour_Event in type date
date_Event in type datetime
```

I would like `hour_Event` to be formatted to `hh:mm`
and `date_Event` to be `dd/mm/yyyy`

I use PHPMyAdmin and im new with MySQL so I dont know how to change the format and for what.

How do I do it?

Comment: Format the data when you query the table, or physically change the stored values?

Comment: @user2502867 Change your format in PHP then insert in DB .

Comment: Why have you got two separate fields.??? The date_Event will hold the time of the event as well as the date. You just get the part you want in your query or by extracting in PHP.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql query - format date on output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596457/mysql-query-format-date-on-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**DATE_FORMAT(hour_Event,'%h:%i')** will give you hour_Event in hh:mm
```

and

```
**DATE_FORMAT(date_Event,'%d/%m/%Y')** will give you date_Event in dd/mm/yyyy
```

Comment: where do I use it? is this somehthing that I exceute every time I insert something or I edit the filed propeties?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the format using php before you insert data or after retrieving themfrom your database according to your needs.You could use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) / [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) & [date()](https://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php). In most cases a single timestamp field in your table is enough for an event.

Have a look here:

[Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Also you could format your field according to your needs with mysql for example:

```
DATE_FORMAT(tables.field, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'new_name'
```

Have a look about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format